# How would i do input validation?

Tags: java

Tells the user if the number entered is even or even. I need help with the input validation. The validation i need do is that the user cannot entered anything but a number. Trying to do the validation without the try and catch method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class oddoreven {
      public static void main (String [] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

         //declaractions
         int num; 

         //while loop
         do{ 
         System.out.println("PLease enter a number to see whether it is even or odd. To end tyype in -99.");
         num = input.nextInt();  

         // input valid


        }while(num != -99);  // loop ends

 // begins the method
      public static void is_odd_or_even_number(int number){   
         int rem = number%2;


      \
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Scanner.hasNextInt()` to determine if the next input is an `int` (and consume anything else). Also, you might make an infinite loop and `break` when the input is `-99` (or `99`, your code tests for `99` but your prompt says `-99`). Finally, you should call your method. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number to see whether it is "
                + "even or odd. To end type in -99.");
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            num = input.nextInt();
            if (num != -99) { // <-- directions say -99.
                is_odd_or_even_number(num);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s is not a valid int.%n", input.nextLine());
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to check whether all the characters of string entered by user are digits or not,

```
 num.matches("[0-9]+") // return true if all characters are digits
```

or

```
 num.matches("^[0-9]*$") // return true if all characters are digits
```

but before that change your `num = input.nextint()`  to  `num = nextLine()`  and make `num` as `String`. if you dont do this there is no need of validating user input as you are requiring.

Comment: `num` is an `int` in the post.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i just ignored that, thought that if OP is asking about validation OP would be taking input as String. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) to get a string input. Then loop through the characters to make sure they are all digits. (assuming non-negative integers only)

```
string rawInput = input.nextLine();
boolean validInput = true;
for (char c : rawInput) {
      if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
           validInput = false;
           break;
      }
}

if (validInput) {
    int num == Integer.parseInt(rawInput);
    // proceed as normal
}
else {
    // invalid input, print out error message
}
```